# Shortening sorted list

Tags: java, algorithm

Suppose you have a sorted List containing server names. You'd like to collapse them as tightly as possible.

Example:

```
abcd01c, abcd02c, abcd04c, abcd05, z1x
```

should become

```
abcd0[1-4]c,abcd05,z1x
```

What is the simplest algorithm to take care of something like this?

Comment: Are these shortened names to be stored as strings? Or are you using `abcd0[1-4]c` in lieu of a special wrapper object?

Comment: Do you know the patterns in advance? (e.g. abcdNNc, abcdNN, etc)

Comment: @Eric I would say it's irrelevant. In this case i would be looking for a simplest possible implementation. They can be strings or a part of some object which understands Prefix/ Range/ Postfix

Comment: @Brian I do not. All i am guaranteed to have is a sorted list of strings, which i should attempt to shorten. Assuming Prefix and Postfix are the same, i would rely on range to be in format [low-high]

Comment: Can you give us a set of rules for collapsing names? Are square bracket ranges only to be used in place of a single character? Does a range define a range of ASCII codes?

Comment: What if you're missing one in the range (like in your example: `abcd01c, abcd02c, abcd04c`) ?

Comment: @ Eric `string_value_common_to_all[low_interger-high_integer]string_value_common_to_all`

Comment: @Brian Good question. In that case we assume that we shortened it the best we could and move on. Using your example, `abcd01c, abcd02c, abcd04c` would become `abcd0[1-2]c,abcd4c`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would store all strings in a prefix map, which makes the decision of a String exists very easy, and also allows fast iteration of a subset of Strings.

Store the Strings as:

```
(0)abcd01c
(5)     2c, 
(5)     4c, 
(4)    05, 
(0)z1x
```

The number is the count of characters which have to be taken from the previous String. This is a common implementation for dictionaries like phonebooks, where you have to store many similar Strings.

A [Trie](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) is a similar structure, as [Brian Roach](https://stackoverflow.com/users/302916/brian-roach) noticed in the comments.

Comment: Generally you use a `Trie` for that ... and I think you could use it here to store everything, you'd just need a custom traversal function to get the data back out in the format needed.

Answer (score 1):

I think dynamic programming can help. The shortest length can be computed for all sets of first elements of given array, i.e. {1}, {1,2}, {1,2,3}... Those numbers are computed consequently, so previous ones are used to calculate the current number. If we want to calculate A[i] and A[j] is known (j < i) and numbers from given array from j+1 to i can be compressed, then A[i] equals A[j] + length of compressed data.

**upd**

I hardly understand how to compress if range is set for more then one symbol. So, here is a simple realization in case of one symbol.

```
int prevIdx = -1;
int count = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < list.Length; i++) {
    bool ok = true;
    if (list[i].Length == list[i - 1].Length) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < list[i].Length; j++)
            if (list[i][j] != list[i - 1][j])
                curIdx = j;
                count++;
            }
        if (count > 1)
            ok = false;
    }
    else
        ok = false;
    if (ok) {
        if (prevIdx == curIdx) {
            count++;
        }
        else {
            prevIdx = curIdx;
            if (count > 1)
                answer.Add(list[i - 1].SubString(0, prevIdx - 1) + 
                    '[' + count.ToString() + ']' + list[i - 1].SubString(prevIdx + 1, list[i - 1].Length);
            else
                answer.Add(list[i - 1]);
            count = 0;
        }
    }
    else {
        if (count > 1)
            answer.Add(list[i - 1].SubString(0, prevIdx - 1) + 
                '[' + count.ToString() + ']' + list[i - 1].SubString(prevIdx + 1, list[i - 1].Length);
        else
            answer.Add(list[i - 1]);
        prevIdx = -1;
    }
}
if (count > 1)
    answer.Add(list[List.Length - 1].SubString(0, prevIdx - 1) + 
        '[' + count.ToString() + ']' + list[i - 1].SubString(prevIdx + 1, list[List.Length - 1].Length);
else
    answer.Add(list[list.Length - 1]);
```

Comment: any chance you can provide an example?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little shaky on what your actual need is, but an approach to this would be in a custom [Trie (Wikipedia Entry)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)

When you reached the point in your key where your next character isn't an alpha character, you'd know that you had a prefix. Inside that node in the Trie you could then have another map (not pointing at additional Trie nodes) that was keyed by the suffix and contained the ranges for each.

You still have the problem, however, of the specific rules around your data. If you have `abcd01c` as the key, is the prefix `abcd` or `abcd0`?